# How to fill empty cells with values from upper non empty cell in libreoffice calc without using macro/coding

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice, calc

I want to fill empty cells with value from upper non-empty cells, ms excel have ctrl+d for doing that. but i want one step further I want to do multi hop ctrl+d.

For Example

A1, A3, A9, A25, A28 have some value and all other cells of column A are empty I want to fill cell A2 with value of A1,cells A4 to A8 with value of A3,cells A10 to A25 with value A9,cells A26 to A27 with value of A25

Other columns also have such empty cells and I want to fill them like I want for column A.

Folowing are images of sample excel:

[image: table with empty cells]

[image: table after filling empty cells]

I can fill the empty cells by grading cell down for each hop. 
For given example I can fill cells by dragging down A1, A3, A9, A25, A28 each.
But I want to do that in one go because I have this type of empty cells and filled cells in between empty cell in thousands.

how can I do that?

Comment: Not working for me: Ctrl-D (or Strg-U since I'm using a German Excel) fills the marked area just with the *first value* overwriting all other values. It's the same in Calc, filling the complete marked area with the same value.

Comment: You seem to have answered this yourself [here](https://superuser.com/q/562944/1059206)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 1st table content is in A1:C15, put :

```
=IF(A2="",E1,A2) in E2

=IF(B2="",F1,B2) in F1

=IF(C2="",G1,C2) in G1
```

and drag downwards..

Hope it solves..

Answer (score 1):

You might like [this trick](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/257164/solved-fill-blank-cells-with-value-from-above/?comment=257278#post-id-257278)
Just use simple formula and Ctrl+Shift+V (Paste Special - Skip Empty Cells)

[image: FillEmptyCells.gif]

Comment: yes, this will solve the problem. Thank You.